# How to turn on and unlock android screen? and the activity must be finished

Tags: android, android-activity, android-wake-lock, unlock

I have a rooted Android, and I am writing a program to turn on, unlock screen, so I wrote two programs

First program can turn on screen, but it cannot unlock the phone, if I finish the activity, it still works.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // turn on screen, actiivty can finish
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "tag");
    wl.acquire();

    finish();
}
```

Second program can turn on screen and unlock the phone, but I cannot finish the activity, if I finish it, it cannot works.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


    // unlock and turn on screen, activity must not finish
    Window window = this.getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);

}
```

If I **must** finish the activity, how can I turn on screen and unlock device in my program?